# How can I remove a "0" value from an event array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript

hello I have an array with the following structure

```
let test = ["testOne:,O,U,0","testTwo:R,C,0","testTree:1.334","testFour:r,z"];
```

I want to go through the array and eliminate the zero character "0" after the "," since I can have number values ​​in some registers ", I have tried pop and slice but I only manage to eliminate by index from the array I want to eliminate those characters from the string in a new array

my expected result would be:

```
let test = ["testOne:,O,U","testTwo:R,C","testTree:1.334","testFour:r,z"];
```

Comment: "I have tried pop and slice but I only manage to eliminate by index from the array" Please show the code that you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` and `replace` to remove `,0` from end of each string

```js
const arr = ["testOne:,O,U,0","testTwo:R,C,0","testTree:1.334","testFour:r,z"];
const res = arr.map(str => str.replace(/,0$/, ""));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `endsWith` method to check and slice the str.
(Assuming always endsWith exactly `,0`, if they are different like `, 0`, this needs to change accordingly)

```js
const arr = [
  "testOne:,O,U,0",
  "testTwo:R,C,0",
  "testTree:1.334",
  "testFour:r,z",
];
const output = arr.map((str) =>
  str.endsWith(",0") ? str.slice(0, str.length - 2) : str
);
console.log(output);
```